# Receiving null in observed livedata instead of object

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, repository-pattern, android-livedata

I am not sure what is exactly happening but when **ApiService.apiService.getPokemon(name)** in fun getPokemon in PokemonRepository.kt is called then the function getPokemon stops executing and emited livedata are then observed as null in **DetailAktivity.kt** instead of a valid Pokemon class.

I have checked the API call and it is working in other cases. I am new to Android programming, so I would appreciate some detailed explanation.

Here are the classes:

**PokemonRepository.kt**

```
class PokemonRepository(context: Context) {
companion object {
    private val TAG = PokemonRepository::class.java.simpleName
}

private val pekemonDao = PokemonDatabase.getInstance(context).pokemonDao()

fun getPokemon(name: String) = liveData {
    val disposable = emitSource(
        pekemonDao.getOne(name).map {
            it
        }
    )
    val pokemon = ApiService.apiService.getPokemon(name)
    try {

        disposable.dispose()
        pekemonDao.insertAllPokemons(pokemon)
        pekemonDao.getOne(name).map {
            it
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Getting data from the Internet failed", e)
        pekemonDao.getOne(name).map {
            e
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity.kt**

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {
    const val ITEM = "item"
}

private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val vm: DetailViewModel by viewModels()

    vm.pokemon.observe(
        this,
        {
            binding.name.text = it.name
            supportActionBar?.apply {
                setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
                title = it.name
            }
        }
    )

    intent.extras?.apply {
        vm.setCharacterId(getString(ITEM)!!)
    }
}
}
```

**DetailViewModel**

```
class DetailViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private val repository = PokemonRepository(application)

private val name: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val pokemon = name.switchMap { name ->
    repository.getPokemon(name)
}

fun setCharacterId(characterId: String) {
    name.value = characterId
}
}
```

**ApiService.kt**

```
interface ApiService {
@GET("pokemon?offset=0&limit=151")
suspend fun getPokemons(@Query("page") page: Int): NamedApiResourceList

@GET("pokemon/{name}")
suspend fun getPokemon(@Path("name") name: String): Pokemon

companion object {

    private const val API_ENDPOINT = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/"
    val apiService by lazy { create() }

    private fun create(): ApiService = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .client(OkHttpClient())
        .build()
        .create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

}

**Pokemon data class**

```
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Entity
data class Pokemon(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "base_experience") val baseExperience: Int,
    val height: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_default") val isDefault: Boolean,
    val order: Int,
    val weight: Int,
    val sprites: PokemonSprites,
) : Parcelable
```

**PokemonDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface PokemonDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM namedapiresource")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<NamedApiResource>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name=:name")
fun getOne(name: String): LiveData<Pokemon>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertAllNamedApiResources(vararg characters: NamedApiResource)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertAllPokemons(vararg characters: Pokemon)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess because of how your `getPokemon` is defined:

```
val disposable = emitSource(
        // Attempts to get a pokemon from the database - presumably this does
        // not exist at first so would return null first
        pekemonDao.getOne(name).map { 
            it
        }
    )
    
    // AFTER NULL IS RETURNED this tries to fetch from the API
    val pokemon = ApiService.apiService.getPokemon(name)
    try {

        disposable.dispose()
        pekemonDao.insertAllPokemons(pokemon)

        // After fetching from API, finally returns a non-null
        pekemonDao.getOne(name).map {
            it
        }
```

So maybe just get ride of the initial block?

```
val disposable = emitSource(
        pekemonDao.getOne(name).map { 
            it
        }
    )
```

Comment: When I delete the initial block, then there occurs an error at livedata with message "Not enough information to infer type variable T". And I also want to check if the data is in the database first.